# Python 3.6 alternative for simpleKML

Tags: python, kml, python-3.6

I am trying to learn how to make KML files within my program. I searched for a while and ran upon simplekml. Looked into it and liked the simplicity it offered. Unfortunetly though I wasn't able to install via anaconda Cloud because my Python version is 3.6 and it seems to only suports upto 3.4. I searched for alternatives and came up with this: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libkml but i don't think it has the same purpose as simplekml.

I wanted to ask what else could be used for anaconda/python 3.6 that offers a simple way of making KML files? I have some coords that I will put into the program and it should create a simple KML file. Any module or code suggestions will be appriciated.

If this question was not supposed to be asked here I apologies. I will delete it if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *have to* use Python 3.6, you can create a virtual environment with an earlier version of python and install the library you want to use. At your command prompt, use `conda` to create the environment, then activate it and add any other packages you need using `conda` or `pip`.

```
> conda create -n mykml python=3.4

> activate mykml       # or `source activate mykml` on Linux/bash

> pip install simplekml
> conda install ...
```

Comment: Even though this answer wasn't what I was looking for I still wanted to thank you for your help. I will keep your answer in mind for future coding. And BTW, I just gave up looking for a simple module etc and ended up manually writing an xml file instead.